# How to differentiate $(\ln n) ^{\ln n}$?

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

$$f(n) = (\ln n)^{\ln n}$$

Can someone explain me how to differentiate the above function?

I am trying the following solution

$$f'(n) = \frac{\ln n\left((\ln n) ^ {\ln n} - 1\right)}{(\frac1n \ln 2)}$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=(\log x)^{\log x}$; then
$$
\log f(x)=\log x\cdot \log\log x
$$
and so, differentiating both sides,
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=
\frac{1}{x}\cdot\log\log x+\log x\cdot\frac{1}{\log x}\cdot \frac{1}{x}=
\frac{1+\log\log x}{x}
$$

If $f(x)=(\log_a x)^{\log_ax}$, then we have again
$$
\log f(x)=\log_ax\cdot \log\log_ax
$$
(no subscript means natural logarithm). So
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=
\frac{1}{x\log a}\cdot\log\log_ax+\log_ax\cdot\frac{1}{\log_ax}\cdot\frac{1}{x\log a}=
\frac{1+\log\log_ax}{x\log a}
$$
remembering that if $g(x)=\log_ax$, then $g'(x)=1/(x\log a)$.

Comment: what if "lg" in my question is log to the base 2?

Comment: @user271017 No real problem. I'll add the method for arbitrary bases.

Comment: @user271017 : you can answer that if the base is anything, otherwise differntiation is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=u^v$ and $u=v=\ln(x)$.  It then follows that

$$\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\frac{vu}{dx}\\&=\frac{vu^{v-1}}x+\frac{\ln(u)u^v}x\\&=\frac{\ln(x)^{\ln(x)}(1+\ln(\ln(x)))}x\end{align}$$

Which follows from the [multi-variable chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions).